# How to properly boil multiple records down into one using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby and Rails while also trying to lose weight. To that end, I've made my first project a dieting app. Each time you eat something, you note its name, caloric value, and sugar, and then you can check a page showing your ongoing calorie deficit, a graph of your history, and so on.

**The problem**: Each meal has its own record, but I need to sum every meal from a given day up into a "Tuesday's total calories" value to use in a table. Before I duct-tape together some sloppy solution, I thought I'd ask what the *proper* way to do something like that is. Is there an ActiveRecord method I can use? If I write my own code to iterate over a month's worth of queries to build up 31 daily values, should I be doing that in my controller, or is there a way to do it in the model?

Comment: On stack overflow you should always try to solve your problems first. The reason is very simple - we will not solve somebody's homework.

Comment: +1 one, show what you tried so far, I will happily point you in the right direction afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over all the meals would be bad, performance wise. Especially for people who do have many meals ;) It would load all the Meal records from the database, and then into memory.

ActiveRecord offers an interface to use the calculation functions provided by your database. It would only take a single query to let the database sum up the calories for a given day, week or month.

You'd do something to this end:

```
total_calories = Meal.where('DATE(created_at) = ?', Date.today).sum(:calories)
```

If you want to retrieve all the meals for the last 30 days with a single SQL query, you can do something like the code below. Notice how it still takes advantage of the `sum` method even with grouping:

```
Meal.where(created_at: 1.month.ago..Time.now)
  .group('DATE(created_at)').order('date_created_at').sum(:calories)
```

Read about the calculation methods in the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html).

Comment: created_at is a timestamp not a date, comparing it with date will only return records created exactly at midnight.

Comment: I used the `DATE` function to convert the timestamp to a date first for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: Ah, true. missed that. :) However this makes a query non-db agnostic. Will not work e.g. in postgre.

Comment: If you want to show the calories for each day of a month, this would result in 30 queries to the database. That will be very slow.

Comment: Very true. Even though you already mentioned it in your answer, I updated my answer with a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can count and group by date in one query:

```
Meal.select('DATE(created_at) AS ordered_date, SUM(calories) AS calories').
     group('DATE(created_at)').
     order('ordered_date')
```

Perhaps you want to at a time range:

```
where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now))
```